Can we copy the Apache Ignite work folder to a new separate node and start separate cluster?
I'm migrating to a new Apache Ignite cluster. I have copied the works folders as backup. Can I put the works folder on to the new cluster and just start the new cluster?

By default Ignite creates a work directory under its installation directory. This can be changed by configuration to any other location. To do this you need to shut down all nodes of your cluster, move the work directory to your desired location and then change the server configuration on all nodes to point to the new desired location. In terms of starting a new server, if you move the work directory for a cluster that is down you could move it back and resume operations under the old server. But you cannot have 2 functional cluster instances operating on 2 different work directory locations!

I'm asking if can I copy the work directory as is to another cluster and start that cluster with that working directory. I'm not asking if I can set different locations or move the work directory. I have 3 work directory copies and 3 new nodes, not on the same cluster or network.

Yes you should be able to do that. The impact of that is you would then have 2 clusters who's data will depart and be different in both time and data in the event that any data operation done on one cluster is not mirrored to the other cluster. If you are OK with that then yes you should be able to do that. Hope that helps.

Yes. Nothing about mirror I just want to move the data to the other cluster and shutdown the other one...
